# Serve Static Files From Flask

Tags: python, flask

My current breakdown is as follows:

```
MyProj/
   www/
      static/
         css/ 
         js/
      templates/
        index.html
   server.py
```

My server.py looks like this

```
import json
import os
from urlparse import urlparse

from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, session
from flask_sslify import SSLify
from rauth import OAuth2Service
import requests

app = Flask('my_app',
            template_folder='www/templates/',
            static_folder='www/static',
            static_url_path='/static'
            )

#app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='static', static_url_path='')
app.requests_session = requests.Session()
app.secret_key = os.urandom(24)

sslify = SSLify(app)
```

...

I have a login/submit that's supposed to do the following

```
 return render_template(
        'index.html',
        token=myGeneratedToken
    )
```

My index.html page launches; however everything that's in my js will not load and I'm given a 404 error for them.

Am I using the static_folder and static_url_path wrong?

Edit 1:  server.py sits at C:\workspace\myproject\server.py

Comment: Where is `server.py`? How are you referencing the static files in your templates?

Comment: Sits at the root level - I just want to have my index.html reference a javascript file sitting in the static folder

Comment: How is your tree directory?

Comment: But how do you reference it from the template? Are you using `url_for`?